# How to model this relation using Java OOP concepts

Tags: java, oop

I have this condition (property rent system, rent is counted per night)

1. Owner has one or more property. Property has `description`, `price`, and `isOccupied` attribute.
2. The property can be: hotel (with 3 room types), flat/apartment, and house for homestay.
3. Through a `registry` function, a customer can order one or more property available at certain date.

Here are the pre-defined conditions for `registry` function:

1. There are 2 registered owners and customers in the system.
2. Owner 1 has 10 hotel rooms (standard type) for US$30 per night and 3 hotel rooms (suite type) for US$60 per night.
3. Owner 2 has 3 apartments for US$70 per night and 5 homestay house for US$20 per night.
4. Customers can rent one or more owner's property for a certain date.

To model the property, I use inheritance concept. For now, it looks something like this.
Property.java

```
public class Property {
    private String description;
    private int propertyPrice;
    private String ownerName; // should it be here? or should it be made in another class?
    private boolean isOccupied;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getPropertyPrice() {
        return propertyPrice;
    }

    public void setPropertyPrice(int propertyPrice) {
        this.propertyPrice = propertyPrice;
    }
}
```

Hotel.java

```
public class Hotel extends Property {
    private String[] roomType;
    private int[] roomCount;
    
    public Hotel(){
        this.roomType = new String[]{"Standard", "Deluxe", "Suite"};
        this.roomCount = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
    }

    public String[] getRoomType() {
        return roomType;
    }

    public void setRoomType(String[] roomType) {
        this.roomType = roomType;
    }

    public int[] getRoomCount() {
        return roomCount;
    }

    public void setRoomCount(int[] roomCount) {
        this.roomCount = roomCount;
    }    
}
```

Apartment.java

```
public class Apartment extends Property {
    private int roomCount;

    public int getRoomCount() {
        return roomCount;
    }

    public void setRoomCount(int roomCount) {
        this.roomCount = roomCount;
    }
}
```

Homestay.java

```
public class HomestayRoom extends Property {
    private String parentName; 

    public String getParentName() {
        return parentName;
    }

    public void setParentName(String parentName) {
        this.parentName = parentName;
    }
}
```

What makes me confused is, how can I define the pre-defined conditions for `registry` to model owner-property relation? Should I make the owner at another class? If so, how can I relate the properties and its owner?

Answer (score 2):

Most of what you have done is correct, but you could also have a property type enum

```
public enum PropertyType{
    HOTEL,APARTMENT,HOMESTAY
}
```

Now you're super class would be

```
public class Property {
    private String description;
    private int propertyPrice;
    private String ownerName;
    private boolean isOccupied;
    private PropertyType pt;
    ....
    }
```

A constructor for hotel would be

```
public Hotel(){
        this.roomType = new String[]{"Standard", "Deluxe", "Suite"};
        this.roomCount = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
        super(PropertyType.HOTEL);
    }
```

Similarly you could have constructors for `Homestay` and `Apartment`, with the extra line of `super(PropertyType.HOMESTAY)` and `super(PropertyType.APARTMENT)` respectively.